# How to add data from one flatlist to another(array of a object) in a single page which has which has same DATA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native, flatlist

```
  const DATA = [
    {
        car_name: 'Ford',
        model_number: '2021 . 68 - 1647',
        full_tank: false,
        suggestion: [
            {
                price: '$2.50',
                type: 'Oil Top up',
                description: 'Max 1 litre of Al Maha synthetic/ mineral oil and service limited to filling up the oil',
                sid: 0,
            },
            {
                price: '$2.50',
                type: 'Oil Top up',
                description: 'Max 1 litre of Al Maha synthetic/ mineral oil and service limited to filling up the oil',
                sid: 1,
            },


        ],
        added_item: [
            {
                price: '$1.50',
                type: 'Solid fuel',
                added_id: 20,
            },
            {
                price: '$2.50',
                type: 'Oil Top up',
                added_id: 21,
            },
            {
                price: '$3.50',
                type: 'Liquid fuels',
                added_id: 22,
            },
            {
                price: '$7.50',
                type: 'spark plugs',
                added_id: 23,
            },
        ],
        id: 0
    },
    {
        car_name: 'Kia',
        model_number: '2021 . 68 - 1647',
        full_tank: false,
        suggestion: [{
            price: '$2.50',
            type: 'Oil Top up',
            description: 'Max 1 litre of Al Maha synthetic/ mineral oil and service limited to filling up the oil',
            sid: 4,
        },
        {
            price: '$2.50',
            type: 'Oil Top up',
            description: 'Max 1 litre of Al Maha synthetic/ mineral oil and service limited to filling up the oil',
            sid: 5,
        },
        {
            price: '$2.50',
            type: 'Oil Top up',
            description: 'Max 1 litre of Al Maha synthetic/ mineral oil and service limited to filling up the oil',
            sid: 6,
        },
        {
            price: '$2.50',
            type: 'Oil Top up',
            description: 'Max 1 litre of Al Maha synthetic/ mineral oil and service limited to filling up the oil',
            sid: 7,
        },],
        added_item: [
            {
                price: '$1.50',
                type: 'Oil Top up',
                added_id: 24,
            },
            {
                price: '$3.50',
                type: 'hose pipes',
                added_id: 25,
            },
            {
                price: '$2.50',
                type: 'air filter',
                added_id: 26,
            },
            {
                price: '$4.50',
                type: 'belts',
                added_id: 27,
            },
        ],
        id: 1
    },
     
]



const [itemData, setItemData] = useState(DATA);



  <FlatList
                            data={itemData}
                            extraData={refresh}
                            keyExtractor={(item) => {
                                item.id
                            }}
                            renderItem={({ item }) => (

                                <View >

                                    <View style={styles.firstRowOfStatus}>


                                        <View>
                                            <Text
                                                style={styles.carName}
                                            >{item.car_name}</Text>
                                            <Text
                                                style={styles.carNumber}
                                            >{item.model_number}</Text>
                                        </View>



                                        <Clickable
                                            style={{ marginEnd: 16 }}
                                            onPress={async () => {

                                                console.log('CLICKED' + item.id);
                                                // showAlertDialog(item);


                                                deleteMyItem(item);
                                                // AlertDialog.hide();
                                                ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(
                                                    "Item has been deleted successfully!",
                                                    ToastAndroid.SHORT,
                                                    ToastAndroid.BOTTOM
                                                );
                                                //   },
                                            }}
                                        >

                                           
                                        </Clickable>
                                    </View>

                                    <View style={styles.secondRow}>

                                    </View>

                                    <FlatList

                                        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                                        data={item.added_item}
                                        
                                        keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
                                            item.added_id
                                        }}
                                        renderItem={({ item }) => (



                                            <View style={{
                                                marginRight: 16,
                                                flexDirection: 'row',
                                                justifyContent: 'space-between',
                                                marginBottom: 8

                                            }}>
                                                <View>
                                                    {
                                                        
                                                    }
                                                    <Text
                                                    style={styles.selected_item_text}>
                                                        {item.type}
                                                    </Text>
                                                </View>
                                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                                    <Text

                                                        style={styles.selected_item_price}
                                                    >{item.price}</Text>
                                                    <Clickable style={{ marginStart: 8 }}
                                                    
                                                    onPress={()=>{
                                                                                          
                                                    }}
                                                    >
                                                        
                                                    </Clickable>

                                                </View>
                                            </View>

                                        )} />
                                    <FlatList
                                        horizontal
                                        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                                        data={item.suggestion}
                                        keyExtractor={(item) => {
                                            item.sid
                                        }}
                                        renderItem={({ item }) => (

                                            <Clickable

                                                onPress={() => {
                                                    console.log("got id====", item.sid);

                                                    let suggestedItem = [];
                                                    suggestedItem.push(item.price)
                                                    console.log(suggestedItem);

                                                    add_service(item)
                                                    //setItemData()
                                                }}
                                                style={styles.singleItemParent}>

                                                <View style={styles.priceTitleView}>
                                                    <Text
                                                        style={
                                                            styles.price
                                                        }
                                                    >
                                                        {item.price}
                                                    </Text>

                                                    <Text
                                                        style={
                                                            styles.price_status
                                                        }
                                                    >{item.type}</Text>
                                                </View>

                                                <View>
                                                    <Text
                                                        style={
                                                            
                                                        }
                                                    >
                                                        {item.description}
                                                    </Text>

                                                </View>

                                           

                                                <Clickable style={{
                                                    justifyContent: 'center',
                                                    alignItems: 'center'
                                                }}
                                                    onPress={() => {
                                                        console.log(item.sid);

                                                    }}
                                                >
                                                    <Text style={styles.add_service_text}>{Strings.str_add_service}</Text>
                                                </Clickable>
                                            </Clickable>

                                        )} />


                                </View>


                            )} />
```

**I want to pass data from flatList (sugession) to another flatList (added_item). How can I pass data from one flatList to another which has single DATA**

*I tried to access specific data by using useEffect but I am getting the list of all suggestions present in an DATA*

please tell me how can I add data from horizontal flatlist to added_items ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhQOB.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have `itemData` with all items. Use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to select your item.

For example:

```
const kiaItem = itemData.find(item => item.car_name === 'Kia');
console.log('kia sugession', kiaIte.sugession);
console.log('kia added_item', kiaIte. added_item);
```